# needn't = don't need to?

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Are these two sentences equivalent?

> You *needn't* pay at once.
>
> You *don't need to* pay at once.

If yes, which one would you recommend? Is it an US/GB thing?

Comment: I think we learned in school they are different, but I forgot what was the difference. I'm curious to know too, so +1

Comment: This question is from May 20, 2011, and has been viewed more than 20,000 times in the past seven years. It's hard to imagine that we would gain any practical benefit from closing it at this point.

Answer (score 10):

They are equivalent in meaning; however, the non contracted forms would be

> You *need not* pay at once.
>   You *do not need to* pay at once.

I think the first is more common in BrE (though I would request confirmation).  The second formation is more common is AmE; however, we would more likely say

> You don't need to pay right away.

Comment: If the former was more common in BrE it is archaic now - I know not of any person who would speak in such a manner.

Comment: It may be archaic for you, @AndyF, it's alive and well for me. But it is true that "need" has been for some while in process of changing from a full auxiliary like "must" into a lexical verb like "want".

Comment: Perhaps a generational or regional distinction then, @Colin? I know for certain that if I used the construction "You needn't shout" instead of "You don't need to shout" it would be considered rather pretentious. I'm not saying that it's wrong, just that I don't hear many people speak that way from day to day (not that they're necessarily correct either, mind you).

Comment: For me, that slightly ironic use in "You needn't shout!" (meaning "please don't shout") is exactly where I would most expect to here "needn't".

Answer (score 6):

I initially just thought **needn't** is probably more British usage, but that it's becoming increasingly archaic / affected.

So I produced [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needn+%27+t&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share&) NGram to support my thinking. Restricting to just American or British doesn't suggest it's much more common in either.

Frankly, I just don't know what to make of [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needn+%27+t&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share&) showing the latest trend.

Nevertheless, I'd still advise OP to use **don't need to**. I doubt anyone would think that meant he wasn't keeping up with the times.

Comment: You can always count on Google to pleasantly surprise you with a new cool service `:)`

Comment: `becoming affected`? It's sick?? Not too sure I understand what you mean by that sentence...

Comment: @Alexis: You should get in the habit of googling things like [**define affected**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/affected) if you don't understand a usage (the second definition there is the relevant one: ***pretentious and designed to impress***).

Comment: Google does not always give you the right answer! Thank you for taking the time to lighten the meaning in this case. We do not have that meaning in French for the verb "affecter".

Comment: @Alexis: On reflection I suppose it might not have been obvious to you sense #2 rather than sense #1 *(influenced or touched by an external factor)* was the one that applied in my usage. It crops up a lot on ELU though, so you'd best remember it! :)

Comment: Hello FF, there is an edit suggestion pending and I think it is suggested because your Ngram Viewer links don't show anything related with needn't or don't need to.

Comment: A)  I don't understand the significance of the Ngram to your answer. B)  Do Brits use the phrase? Is it generational?

Comment: @Clare: NGrams / Google Books don't handle apostrophes very well (plus they always tend to over-represent older and more formal written forms over current natural speech). Presumably my intention (over 6 years ago) was to provide statistical evidence to support what I said in my answer. The fact of the matter is the vast majority of native speakers would rarely if ever say things like *You needn't go* - they'd say *You don't need to go.* I think it's a bit pointless speculating as to whether the few that *do* still use the outdated form are concentrated by region, age group, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: These are far below _needn't_ and _don't have to_, which are both above _don't need to_, but just for fun, here are some [colloquialisms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don+%27+t+gotta%2Cain+%27+t+gotta%2Cdon+%27+t+got+to%2Cain+%27+t+got+to&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdon%20%27%20t%20gotta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cain%20%27%20t%20gotta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdon%20%27%20t%20got%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cain%20%27%20t%20got%20to%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @shoover: Don't get me started! Whenever I flag up the AmE usage *What do you got?*, everyone here assures me I'm simply mishearing *What [**'ve**] you got?*, but I've often heard the "syntactic garbage" version enunciated so clearly that it's simply not possible to believe the speaker didn't *intend* to use the verb ***to do***.

Answer (score 5):

We can both use need not and don't need to. However, if needn't is followed by an object, we must use don't need.

> For example : You don't need your coat. It's not cold outside.

"Coat" is an object, so it is wrong to say ,"You needn't your coat".

Answer (score -1):

When the Americans want to express a lack of obligation, they use the helping verb (do) with negative (not) followed by need.
Brits drop the helping verb and contract not

You needn't pay at once. Brits

You don't need to pay at once. Americans

that simple

Comment: Do you have some reference that supports this explanation?

Comment: As a 30-something Brit, nah. "needn't" sounds archaic.

Comment: @AndyT: As a 60-something Brit, I suggest "archaic" might be a bit strong ([though I dissent not](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22though+I+dissent+not%22) from your substantive point - it's at the very least a dated / formal usage today! :) Whatever - I *seriously* disagree with the conflation of Brits and "old-fashioned" constructions implied by this answer. If anything, I'd say on average AmE tends to preserve older forms more than BrE in natural spoken contexts today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'd be happy to call it "dated" rather than "archaic", but I stole the word from your own answer... ;)

Comment: @AndyT: Hoist by my own petard! In my defence, I did try to "hedge" my assertion by saying it was ***becoming increasingly*** so, and conflating ***archaic*** with ***affected***. Mind you, if this question had been asked *today*, I'd have voted to migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than posting an answer here.

Answer (score -2):

They are not equivalent.

*You needn't pay* means that you paid and you're sorry you did.

*You don't need to pay* mean that you didn't pay and don't have to.

Comment: That's wrong actually. You need**n't** have paid (payment was **un**necessary) You **didn't** need to pay (payment was **not** necessary)